# Populate PHP Objects from MYSQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, class, oop, object

When population multiple objects in PHP from a database, what is the best way to do so? My thoughts are the options would be...

- Query the Database, loop through the results and create the object based off the data.
- Pass a Database handle to the class and query the information in the constructor.

I am leaning towards the first option for efficiency to avoid extensive queries, however as there are a lot of properties for each object and PHP lacks structs, it seems silly to pass in dozens of parameters to the constructor.

What is the most efficient way to handle this?

Comment: How about [`Reflection`](http://php.net/reflection) with [`newInstanceArgs()`](http://ru2.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.newinstanceargs.php) + `Factory` pattern ?

Comment: Sounds nice but as I am not familiar with any of that (intermediate PHP knowledge) I have no idea how that would be implemented.

Comment: I am assuming that you have already a class that has attributes mapped exactly to your table columns. That being done, all you need to do is Query and fetch all the related rows from database (one time) and all the results in the list of objects one by one, "maybe using a foreach loop". Now each cell in you list has a database row that can be consumed within the application.

Comment: Are you suggesting just to use Setters in the class and set each property on each class in the foreach loop? That would probably be the most feasible idea if nothing else better is available.

Comment: I suggest you look at [**PDO**](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) especially `FETCH_CLASS` or  `FETCH_OBJ`

Answer (score -2):

Use a "while" statement.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Table1");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo $row['Item1'] . " " . $row['Item2'];
echo "<br>";
}
```

This will do a while loop to check your database for the criteria. Since we SELECT * or "ALL" it will loop through the whole DB. $row is being assigned as an array for the multiple items.
Then each loop prints Item1 and Item2 from the DB.

Let me know if you need a better explanaition :D

Comment: of course you can echo the array items out as you prefer on the page this is just an example of how to make them readily available

Comment: This does not answer the question at all. I am more than aware of how to query the database and loop the results. My question is how to populate potentially hundreds of objects with the data where there are many properties.

Comment: I don't understand how this doesn't help? If you know how to query and how to loop and assign them to variables/arrays then how do you not know how to assign that value to an object. You asked which way would be best and I gave you my opinion no need to be rude about it.

Comment: Actually I think I understand what you are asking now, and I actually don't have an answer for that sorry.

Comment: of course it would be easier to answer if we could see a bit of code or an example?

Comment: It is a concept question, I am not sure where code would be needed.